# Google Map API response is Daily Limit Exceeded

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am developing an autocomplete population with Jquery UI Autocomplete.

I am using the Google Map Places autocomplete API for this.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

But **its showing that the daily limit is exceeded.**

And I also tried the Maps JavaScript API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

But its not working properly and the control of page will be from Google.

I want to know these points.

1. What are the difference between the above two API's
2. How Can I fix the limit exceed issue ?
3. How much is the Limit of Google Map Places autocomplete API and Maps JavaScript API.

Comment: Are you including a key with the API request?

Comment: yes. But the key is free one

Comment: What does the google console show for that key?  Are you really using the daily quota?  What error message are you getting?

Comment: Its getting "your daily limit quota exceeded"

Answer (score 1):

Starting from June 22, 2016 Google counts client side services requests against corresponding web service quota.

https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

> We now count Google Maps JavaScript API client-side requests towards the daily limit of the associated web service API.*

In your case autocomplete uses a daily quota for Places API Web Service. By default the daily quota for Places API is 1000 requests. You can enable Billing in your project and get 150 000 daily requests for free.

Please refer to the documentation for more details:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage